# RabbitVCS 0.15.0.3 PMT / BUG # option not available on commit [Fedora]

Tags: fedora

RabbitVCS 0.15.0.3 PMT  / BUG # option not available with fedora on commit ? But we are able to do the same on Windows with tortoiseSVN 1.6.6.

Version details :

```
RabbitVCS 0.15.0.3
Subversion - 1.6.17.
Pysvn - 1.7.2.0
ConfigObj - 4.7.2
```

OS Version : Fedora 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same feature is working with subeclipse plugin in Eclipse-indigo and Fedora15.
For This I done the following

From Eclipse ,Right clicked the imported svn project
 Select Team --> Set Property
    Name : bugtraq:message
    Value : %BUGID%
and save this property

Select Team --> Set Property
  Name : bugtraq:label
  Value: PMT/BUG#
and save this property also

select Team--> Show Properties 
And found the above added properties are listed

Then try to commit a file It shows the space to enter PMT/BUG along with message.

But the same thing I tried with Rabbitvcs it is not working.

Can anybody help me to work the feature to enter PMT/BUG# along with  commit details in RabbitVcs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But it makes more resource intensive and makes the  Eclipse  slow ! . So do there any solution with RabbitVCS ?